# Git error: command `git reset --hard 742425ade4bb66db573dc13bf436a8f3c87b733b`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, ransack, gemfile, gemfile.lock

recently I've tryed to clone the repository of my agency, and I got this error on **ActiveAdmin** and **Ransack**.

I tryed to clean the cache, change activeadmin version on Gemfile, delete the revision... and I can't found a solution to this problem:

---

```
➜ bundle
The git source `git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
The git source `git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git
fatal: Could not parse object '742425ade4bb66db573dc13bf436a8f3c87b733b'.
Git error: command `git reset --hard 742425ade4bb66db573dc13bf436a8f3c87b733b` in directory /Users/web01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@atua/bundler/gems/ransack-742425ade4bb has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/web01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@atua/cache/bundler/git/ransack-ed28102a2b46bd0d8ac98ce8cee4fd3d73f75680'
```

---

If I can't solve this, I will not be able to do some changes on the agency website..

### Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git
  revision: ffa68b335c87dcf485aab0107c245565f4d2dbd8
  specs:
    activeadmin (1.0.0.pre)
      arbre (~> 1.0)
      bourbon
      coffee-rails
      formtastic (~> 2.3.0.rc3)
      inherited_resources (~> 1.4.1)
      jquery-rails
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.15)
      rails (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
      ransack (~> 1.0)
      sass-rails

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git
  revision: 742425ade4bb66db573dc13bf436a8f3c87b733b
  branch: rails-4.1
  specs:
    ransack (1.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (~> 1.1)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.5)
      actionpack (= 4.1.5)
      actionview (= 4.1.5)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.5)
      actionview (= 4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      rack (~> 1.5.3)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    active_skin (0.0.9)
    activemodel (4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.5)
      activemodel (= 4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.5)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arbre (1.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bourbon (3.2.3)
      sass (~> 3.2)
      thor
    builder (3.2.2)
    celluloid (0.16.0)
      timers (~> 4.0.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.4)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.1)
    connection_pool (2.2.0)
    daemons (1.2.4)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.3.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.3)
    execjs (2.2.1)
    formtastic (2.3.0.rc4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
    has_scope (0.6.0.rc)
      actionpack (>= 3.2, < 5)
      activesupport (>= 3.2, < 5)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hitimes (1.2.2)
    httparty (0.14.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.6.11)
    inherited_resources (1.4.1)
      has_scope (~> 0.6.0.rc)
      responders (~> 1.0.0.rc)
    jbuilder (2.1.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.1)
    kaminari (0.16.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    kgio (2.10.0)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mina (0.3.0)
      open4
      rake
    minitest (5.4.0)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.18)
    open4 (1.3.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (4.2.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types
    polyamorous (1.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    pry (0.10.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-nav (0.2.4)
      pry (>= 0.9.10, < 0.11.0)
    rack (1.5.3)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.5)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.5)
      actionpack (= 4.1.5)
      actionview (= 4.1.5)
      activemodel (= 4.1.5)
      activerecord (= 4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.5)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.1.5)
      actionpack (= 4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.16.0)
    rake (10.3.2)
    redis (3.2.1)
    redis-namespace (1.5.2)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    responders (1.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sidekiq (2.14.1)
      celluloid (>= 0.14.1)
      connection_pool (>= 1.0.0)
      json
      redis (>= 3.0.4)
      redis-namespace (>= 1.3.1)
    sinatra (1.4.6)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    slim (3.0.3)
      temple (~> 0.7.3)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    temple (0.7.5)
    thin (1.7.1)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (>= 1, < 3)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timers (4.0.1)
      hitimes
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (2.2.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unicorn (5.0.1)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    unicorn-rails (2.2.0)
      rack
      unicorn
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_skin
  activeadmin!
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  devise (~> 3.3.0)
  formtastic (~> 2.3.0.rc3)
  httparty
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  mina
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.17)
  paperclip (~> 4.2.0)
  polyamorous (~> 1.1.0)
  pry
  pry-nav
  rails (= 4.1.5)
  ransack!
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  sidekiq (~> 2.14.0)
  sinatra
  slim
  thin
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  unicorn-rails
```

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'unicorn-rails', group: :production
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
gem 'mysql2', "~> 0.3.17"

# assets group
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 2.14.0'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
gem 'httparty'

# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
# development group
gem 'thin',              group: :development
gem 'better_errors',     group: :development
gem 'binding_of_caller', group: :development

# custom gems
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.0'
gem 'mina'

# active admin dependencies
gem 'devise',      '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'polyamorous', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'formtastic',  '~> 2.3.0.rc3' # change to 2.3 when stable is released
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack', branch: 'rails-4.1'
gem 'active_skin'

# debugger gem
gem 'pry',     group: :development
gem 'pry-nav', group: :development
```

Answer (score 1):

The commit still exists in the ransack repo. Try `gem pristine --all` to reset all gems to their downloaded version.